# compatibility of the offsetExists method in the Illuminate\Support\Collection class. DigitalOcean

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean

I have a Larvel application I am trying to deploy to DigitalOcean, on deploying I was faced with the following errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php:1443
> Stack trace:
> #0 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php(13): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()
> #1 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(576): include('...')
> #2 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\Autoload{closure}()
> #3 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php(15): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
> #4 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): collect()
> #5 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()
> #6 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
> #7 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(237): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
> #8 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()
> #9 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
> #10 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
> #11 {main} in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php on line 13
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Collection" not found in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php:15
> Stack trace:
> #0 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ReflectsClosures.php(24): collect()
> #1 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ReflectsClosures.php(43): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->closureParameterTypes()
> #2 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/ReportableHandler.php(62): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->firstClosureParameterType()
> #3 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(232): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\ReportableHandler->handles()
> #4 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(88): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report()
> #5 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException()
> #6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
> #7 {main}
> thrown in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/helpers.php on line 15

But when I run (application) it locally (wampserver) everything run smothly without issues. Can someone please tell me what could be wrong?

I have tried doing the following:

1. Changed php version in composer to server php version
2. composer update

But none of the above solutions worked.